# puppet/hiera : the module class cannot be found durins a puppet apply

Tags: puppet, test-kitchen, hiera

During a kitchen converge, calling a puppet apply, i got this error :

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::alibi for ... at .. entry.pp
```

alibi is the module name, and :

```
/tmp/kitchen>ll
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 4 kitchen kitchen  80 Feb 26 14:14 hiera
 -rw-rw-r--. 1 kitchen kitchen 170 Feb 26 14:14 hiera.global.yaml
drwxrwxr-x. 2 kitchen kitchen 100 Feb 26 14:35 manifests
drwxrwxr-x. 4 kitchen kitchen  80 Feb 26 14:14 modules
-rw-rw-r--. 1 kitchen kitchen 901 Feb 26 13:53 puppet.conf
/tmp/kitchen>more  manifests/entry.pp manifests/init.pp
::::::::::::::
manifests/entry.pp
::::::::::::::
  hiera_include('classes')
::::::::::::::
manifests/init.pp
::::::::::::::

class alibi () {

    $instances = hiera_hash("alibi::instances", {})
    validate_hash($instances)
    create_resources("alibi::instance", $instances)

}
/tmp/kitchen>/tmp/kitchen>more hiera.global.yaml
---
:backends:
- yaml

:yaml:
 :datadir: "/tmp/kitchen/hiera"

:hierarchy:

- tests/%{hostname}
- origin/main

# options are native, deep, deeper
:merge_behavior: deeper
/tmp/kitchen>/tmp/kitchen>more hiera/origin/main.yaml
classes:
 - alibi
```

The command is

```
 export MANIFESTDIR='/tmp/kitchen/manifests'; sudo -E env 
 http_proxy=http://proxy-internet.localnet:3128 
 https_proxy=http://proxy-internet.localnet:3128  puppet apply 
 /tmp/kitchen/manifests/entry.pp --modulepath=/tmp/kitchen/modules 
 --fileserverconfig=/tmp/kitchen/fileserver.conf 
 --hiera_config=/tmp/kitchen/hiera.global.yaml --detailed-exitcodes -v
```

Its ok if I use init.pp instead of entry.pp (but hiera_include() is not called)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be properly placed in modules.  When Puppet looks for a class named `alibi`, it will check each directory in your modulepath (unclear what that is in your case, but possibly just `/tmp/kitchen/modules`) for a file `alibi/manifests/init.pp`.  The working directory and manifest directory are irrelevant, at least in any version of Puppet that ought still to be in use anywhere.

This particular name is a bit of a special case, however, because it will be interpreted as the name of a module's main class.  A other classes and defined types in the same module will be mapped a bit differently.  For example, `alibi::good` would be mapped to `alibi/manifests/good.pp`, and `alibi::alibi` would be mapped to `alibi/manifests/alibi.pp`.

> Its ok if I use init.pp instead of entry.pp (but hiera_include() is not called)

Well, yes and no.  Puppet does not rely on file mapping conventions and does check the current directory when you explicitly tell it which file to evaluate.  Therefore, when you explicitly name `init.pp` to it, it finds and evaluates that file.  But no, evaluating that file by itself is of little use: Puppet will parse the class declaration, but there is nothing in that manifest that says to *apply* that class to the target node.

Comment: Thanks john, I can't change the choosen paths like this ... it's a transversal tool which is used by many modules, which work .. so I'm going to try to see the difference between those aned this module which explains why the class alibi is not found

Comment: @Minstrel, if you mean that your tool is "used by many modules" in *Puppet's* sense of the word "module", then you will surely find that the working modules are arranged exactly as I describe.  That's part of being a (working) module.  As I said, your problem is that your class is not in a module.

Comment: I assure you that the kitchen engine model is the same for all modules.
Maybe this will help : when I converge, kitchen creates the hierarchy /tmp/kitchen/moduleNamewhichWorks/etc ... and other dependances like /tmp/kitchen/stdlib/ 

With alibi, it creates this :
`drwxrwxr-x. 7 kitchen kitchen 360 Feb 26 14:14 NAME OF CLASS IN INIT.PP
    drwxrwxr-x. 6 kitchen kitchen 360 Feb 26 14:14 stdlib`

if we knew from which code does this generic name come, it will help

Comment: What version of Puppet are you using, @Minstrel? If you're unwilling or unable to use a standard layout of your Puppet manifests then there are potential workarounds, but which ones are available depends on Puppet version.

Comment: an old one ... 3.8.7
migration to 6.x is planned !

Comment: @Minstrel, In Puppet 3.8, one manifest can [`import`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/lang_import.html) one or more others to have access to classes, defined types, node declarations, and variables declared within.  Note well, however, that (1) it is a Python-like "import", not a lexical interpolation, (2) `import` was deprecated in Puppet 3.8 and removed in Puppet 4, and (3) almost all uses of `import` were considered poor style even in Puppet 2.

Comment: Eureka ! I'm very sorry John, I didn't know that the puppet file used metadata ....  

And this generic name comes from the matadata.json template ....